# импорт базы данных navicat

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть файл.backup это импорт базы данных, хочу открыть ее на локалхосте, у меня стоит postgresql, я пользуюсь навикатом, как мне поставить на него бэкап?

Comment: на чем бекап создавали и каком формате?

Comment: @Saidolim создавал не я, не знаю, формат файла BACKUP

Comment: тогда слодно сказать. Проверьте файл. Если простой sql тогда можете загрузить через navicat, если текст, нужно отредактировать и импортировать через navicat. Если zip тогда psql

Comment: @Saidolim А как его можно проверить?